# Assigning one value to another value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models din & company, on one of the form I am trying to create a functionality in which one can assign Directors to the respected company & company can be assigned to the directors. Here one company can have many directors & director can be on board of many companies.

I have implemented the relation between the above two models using HABTM,I have created one model coDir in which the relation between two will be saved as a combination of din_id & company_id.  I am trying to use two drop down menus where multiple selection is to be used.Now the problem is that how can I assign the directors to the companies & vice versa.

If any one has any idea will save my weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use has_many :through in this case. And use checkboxes for your desired functionality(although you could probably use a multiple select if you wish. Here are a couple of example tutorials to get you started:

http://millarian.com/programming/ruby-on-rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/

http://paulbarry.com/articles/2007/10/24/has_many-through-checkboxes

Comment: thanks for the help, I will go through the links & let you know.